# How do i calculate the inverse of trigonometric functions for a Javascript calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

I am developing my Javascript skills by creating my own scientific calculator that has the basic functions and operators. I have successfully been able to make the Sin, Cos and Tan work by converting the values from radians to degrees. But when I do the same for the inverses I run into several errors.

This is the full code:
`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Natural Display Calculator</title>
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!-- <script src="math.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="
    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/12.2.1/math.min.js
    "></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/10.3.1/decimal.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="display">
            <input type="text" placeholder="0" id="input" disabled />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <!-- Additional functions -->
            <button value="pi" class="constant-button button">π</button>
            <button value="sqrt" class="function-button button">√</button>
            <button value="^" class="function-button button">^</button>
            <button value="sqrt3" class="function-button button">∛</button>
            <button value="(" class="function-button button">(</button>
            <button value=")" class="function-button button">)</button>
            <button value="x^2" class="function-button button">x²</button>

            <!-- Trigonometric functions -->
            <button value="sin" class="function-button button">sin</button>
            <button value="cos" class="function-button button">cos</button>
            <button value="tan" class="function-button button">tan</button>
            <button value="asin" class="function-button button">sin⁻¹</button>
            <button value="acos" class="function-button button">cos⁻¹</button>
            <button value="atan" class="function-button button">tan⁻¹</button>

            <!-- Logarithmic functions -->
            <button value="log" class="function-button button">log</button>
            <button value="ln" class="function-button button">ln</button>

            <!-- Memory operations -->
            <button value="M+" class="function-button button">M+</button>
            <button value="M-" class="function-button button">M-</button>
            <button value="MR" class="function-button button">MR</button>
            <button value="MC" class="function-button button">MC</button>
            <button value="1/x" class="function-button button">x⁻¹</button>

            <button value="x" class="operation-button button">x</button>
            <button value="÷" class="operation-button button">÷</button>
            <button value="DEL" id="erase">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-backspace-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M15.683 3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-7.08a2 2 0 0 0-1.519.698L.241 7.35a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.302l4.843 5.65A2 2 0 0 0 6.603 15h7.08a2 2 0 0 0 2-2zM5.829 5.854a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.708l2.147 2.147 2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 1 1 .707.708L9.39 8l2.146 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.708L8.683 8.707l-2.147 2.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.708L7.976 8z" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <!-- Full Erase -->
            <button value="AC" id="clear">AC</button>
            <button value="7" class="digit-button button">7</button>
            <button value="8" class="digit-button button">8</button>
            <button value="9" class="digit-button button">9</button>
            <button value="-" class="operation-button button">-</button>

            <button value="6" class="digit-button button">6</button>
            <button value="5" class="digit-button button">5</button>
            <button value="4" class="digit-button button">4</button>
            <button value="+" class="operation-button button">+</button>

            <button value="1" class="digit-button button">1</button>
            <button value="2" class="digit-button button">2</button>
            <button value="3" class="digit-button button">3</button>

            <button value="=" id="equal" class="function-button">=</button>
            <button value="0" class="digit-button button">0</button>
            <button value="." class="digit-button button">.</button>
            <button value="ANS" class="variable-button button">ANS</button>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const display = document.getElementById("input");
    const digitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".digit-button");
    const decimalButton = document.querySelector('button[value="."]');
    const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operation-button");
    const equalButton = document.getElementById("equal");
    const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
    const deleteButton = document.querySelector('button[value="DEL"]');
    const ansButton = document.querySelector('button[value="ANS"]');
    const openParenthesesButton = document.querySelector('button[value="("]');
    const closeParenthesesButton = document.querySelector('button[value=")"]');
    const powerButton = document.querySelector('button[value="^"]');
    const squareButton = document.querySelector('button[value="x^2"]');
    const piButton = document.querySelector('button[value="pi"]');
    const sqrtButton = document.querySelector('button[value="sqrt"]');
    const cbrtButton = document.querySelector('button[value="sqrt3"]');
    const sinButton = document.querySelector('button[value="sin"]');
    const cosButton = document.querySelector('button[value="cos"]');
    const tanButton = document.querySelector('button[value="tan"]');
    const asinButton = document.querySelector('button[value="asin"]');
    const acosButton = document.querySelector('button[value="acos"]');
    const atanButton = document.querySelector('button[value="atan"]');

    let rawExpression = '';

    // Function to adjust input's scroll position to show the end of content
    function adjustInputScroll() {
        const input = document.getElementById("input");
        input.scrollLeft = input.scrollWidth; // Scrolls to the end of content
    }

    // Function to update the display with formatted expression
    function updateDisplay(expression) {
        const formattedExpression = expression
            .replace(/\*\*/g, "^")
            .replace(/\*\(/g, "(")
            .replace(/\*/g, "×")
            .replace(/\//g, "÷")
            .replace(/\^2/g, "²")
            .replace(/PI/g, "π")
            .replace(/sqrt/g, "√")
            .replace(/cbrt/g, "∛")
            .replace(/asin/g, "sin⁻¹(")
            .replace(/acos/g, "cos⁻¹(")
            .replace(/atan/g, "tan⁻¹(");
        display.value = formattedExpression;
        adjustInputScroll();
    }

    let isDegreeMode = true;

    // Add click event listeners to digit buttons
    digitButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            const digit = button.value;
            rawExpression += digit;
            updateDisplay(rawExpression);
        });
    });

    // Handle the decimal point
    decimalButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (!rawExpression.includes(".")) {
            rawExpression += ".";
            updateDisplay(rawExpression);
        }
    });

    // Handle operator buttons (+, -, *, /)
    operatorButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            let operator = button.value;
            if (operator === "x") {
                operator = "*";
            } else if (operator === "÷") {
                operator = "/";
            }
            rawExpression += ` ${operator} `;
            updateDisplay(rawExpression);
        });
    });

    // Function to evaluate the expression
    function evaluateExpression(expression) {
        try {
            const scope = {
                sin: isDegreeMode ? degrees => Math.sin((degrees * Math.PI) / 180) : Math.sin,
                cos: isDegreeMode ? degrees => Math.cos((degrees * Math.PI) / 180) : Math.cos,
                tan: isDegreeMode ? degrees => Math.tan((degrees * Math.PI) / 180) : Math.tan,
                sqrt: Math.sqrt,
                cbrt: Math.cbrt,
            };
            const result = math.evaluate(expression, scope);

            // Round numbers like 0.99999 to 1
            const roundedResult = Number.isFinite(result) && Math.abs(result - Math.round(result)) < Number.EPSILON
                ? Math.round(result)
                : result;

            return roundedResult.toString();
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
            return "Error";
        }
    }

        
    // Handle the equal button (=)
    equalButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression = evaluateExpression(rawExpression);
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the clear button (AC)
    clearButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression = "";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the delete button (DEL)
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression = rawExpression.slice(0, -1);
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the ANS button
    ansButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const lastResult = rawExpression;
        rawExpression += lastResult;
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the open parentheses button "("
    openParenthesesButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "*(";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the close parentheses button ")"
    closeParenthesesButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += ")";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the power button "^"
    powerButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "**";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the square button "x^2"
    squareButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "**2";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the pi button
    piButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "PI";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the square root button
    sqrtButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "sqrt(";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the cube root button
    cbrtButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "cbrt(";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the sine button
    sinButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "sin(";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the cosine button
    cosButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "cos(";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the tangent button
    tanButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "tan(";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the inverse sine button
    asinButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "asin";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the inverse cosine button
    acosButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "acos";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

    // Handle the inverse tangent button
    atanButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        rawExpression += "atan";
        updateDisplay(rawExpression);
    });

});

</script>
</body>

</html>`
```

This is the error it currently throws if I press 'tan⁻¹(1)' into the calculator (which is 45):

```
script.js:102  SyntaxError: Unexpected operator ) (char 6) (at math.min.js:1:511697)
at ie (math.min.js:1:511697)
at S (math.min.js:1:504854)
at string (math.min.js:1:501286)
at parse (math.min.js:1:119763)
at string, Map | Object (math.min.js:1:513032)
at Object.evaluate (math.min.js:1:119763)
at evaluateExpression (script.js:93:33)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:110:25)

And this is the error it currently throws if I press 'tan⁻¹(1' into the calculator (Note that I didn't put closing bracket in the expression.) (which is 45):
script.js:102 
Error: Undefined symbol atan1
at Function.value (math.min.js:1:494193)
at math.min.js:1:493169
at Object.evaluate (math.min.js:1:433651)
at string, Map | Object (math.min.js:1:513047)
at Object.evaluate (math.min.js:1:119763)
at evaluateExpression (script.js:93:33)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:110:25)
```

I tried using several methods and tried different methods I found online and even from Math.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The errors occur because your code generates invalid expressions that misses open parentheses after "atan". You can fix it as below:

- Append open parentheses to "asin", "acos", and "atan" when the corresponding buttons are clicked.
- Remove open parentheses when replacing the above math functions with "sin⁻¹(", "cos⁻¹(", and "atan⁻¹(", respectively.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I can't believe it is such a minor mistake that stressed me for hours!